# programatically created bundled product : option and product do not show on frontend unless saved from admin

Tags: magento-1.7, bundled-product, code

i have programmatically created bundled product and also able to add selection and option data to it, but my problem is that product is not visible in front end. when i save that product even without changing the any of the fields in admin, it starts getting displayed.

i am stuck and have no idea what to do if you have any idea please help me out. below is the code is used

```
$storeID = 0;
$websiteIDs = array(1);
$cats = array(19);

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

/** @var $productCheck Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
$productCheck = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

$p = array(
        'sku_type' => 1, //0 = dynamic, 1 = fixed
        'sku' => '687',
        'name' => "BarProduct",
        'description' => 'Foo',
        'short_description' => 'Bar',
        'type_id' => 'bundle',
        'attribute_set_id' => 4,
        'weight_type' => 0, //0 = dynamic, 1 = fixed
        'visibility' => 4,
        'price_type' => 0, //0 = dynamic, 1 = fixed
        'price_view' => 0, //0 = as low as, 1 = price range <---- DOES NOT SEEM TO HAVE ANY EFFECT
        'status' => 1,
        'category_ids' => $cats,
        'store_id' => $storeID,
        'website_ids' => $websiteIDs
);
$productCheck->setData($p);
$productCheck->setStockData(array(
        'is_in_stock' => 1,
        'qty' => 1
    ));


Mage::register('product', $productCheck);

$selectionRawData = array();
$selectionRawData[0] = array();

$optionRawData = array();
$ChildProduct = array(1,2);
$i = 0;
foreach ($ChildProduct as $child){
    $optionRawData[$i] = array(
            'required' => 1,
            'option_id' => '',
            'position' => 0,
            'type' => 'select',
            'title' => 'FooOption',
            'default_title' => 'FooOption',
            'delete' => '',
    );

    $selectionRawData[$i][0] = array(
            'product_id' => $child,
            'selection_qty' => 1,
            'selection_can_change_qty' => 0,  // 1-> yes, 0 -> no
            'position' => 0,
            'is_default' => 1,
            'selection_id' => '',
            'selection_price_type' => 0,
            'selection_price_value' => 0.0,
            'option_id' => '',
            'delete' => ''
    );

$i++;
}

Mage::register('productCheck', $productCheck);
Mage::register('current_product', $productCheck);
$productCheck->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(false);
$productCheck->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
$productCheck->setCanSaveBundleSelections(true);
// Set the Bundle Options
$productCheck->setBundleOptionsData($optionRawData);
//set option data
$productCheck->setBundleSelectionsData($selectionRawData);

$productCheck->setAffectBundleProductSelections(true);

$productCheck->save();
```

Comment: Could it be a reindexing issue? The index is refreshed upon saving a product. Try and refresh them from the backend after importing.

Comment: tried reindexing, dint work..

Comment: Hi did you solve your problem?

Comment: @Martin try using the above code its working, i have updated it

Comment: i found it added as answer, in my case was it a fixed price

Comment: After [this edit](http://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/7824/revisions) the question doesn't make sense anymore and won't help anybody else. Voted to close as "not reproducible".

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code when initializing Mage before creating products:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(
                Mage::getModel('core/store')
                        ->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)
);
```

and they seem to be saving without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is how you are setting to store id to the product:

```
$storeID = 0;
```

Store Id 0 is the admin store so it would appear that you are adding the products only to the admin store. If this is the case they would not appear on any other store. Further more when you save the product in the admin section this then sets the store id correctly and so the product will now appear.

I would suggest either setting this value to the correct id or loading the id from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
//Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
Mage::app('admin');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case

`'price_type' => 0, //0 = dynamic, 1 = fixed`

must be set to 1 (item must have price),

```
'price_type' => 1, //0 = dynamic, 1 = fixed
```

Or

```
$__magproduct->setPriceType(1); //0 = dynamic, 1 = fixed
```

in object mode.

Answer (score -1):

Just set website id in the end, just before product save.

```
$productCheck->setWebsiteIds(array(0));
$productCheck->save();
```

Comment: everything is perfect in these code, created nearly 20K products using these code, just some code's were placed at wrong place